# Outputting dictionary results for all indexes

Tags: python

I'm trying to output some keys, for all indexes, e.g:

```
print results["result"][0]["name"]
```

prints out the first key with no problems, and so does [1], [2], etc. I want to be able to print all indexes, for the value "name". I'm sure it uses a for loop, and tried several methods, but have failed.

How can I print the results for all indexes, not just 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `results['result']` *is a* `list`, use a `for` loop to iterate over the items in that list:

```
for item in results['result']:
    print(item['name'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to output some data I was looking for, and your response is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So assuming `results` is a dictionary-like object, `results["result"]` is a *list* containing dictionary-like elements, where these elements have a key `"name"`,

You could use a list comprehension:

```
print([e["name"] for e in results["result"])
```

If `results["result"]` is a *dict*, this would be:

```
print([e["name"] for e in results["result"].values())
# or, less efficiently
print([results["result"][e]["name"] for e in results["result"])
```

Comment: @MalikBrahimi It also creates a list of `None` values unnecessarily.  If you want an inline for loop, just use `for i in results["result"]: print(i["name"])`.

Comment: Corrected now. Joined the items with newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Just join the list comprehension with newlines:

```
print '\n'.join(i["name"] for i in results["result"])
```